# Chess Board Color changes

Tags: chessboard

Can someone help me recreate this chess board style:

[image]

I got this:

```
    \setboardfontcolors{
blackfieldmask=cyan}
\setboardfontencoding{LSBC3}\storechessboardstyle{zeit}{blackfieldcolor=cyan,setfontcolors,whitepiececolor=black,blackpiececolor=black,pgfstyle=border,borderwidth=1mm,bordercolor=black}
```

Comment: the chessboard documentation has lots of examples of colored boards.